# How to make a contenteditable text ellipsis in IE and Edge?

Tags: html, css, contenteditable, microsoft-edge

In the simple demonstration below you can see that the text is not ellipsis in IE and Edge. In Firefox and Chrome, it is.

Does somebody have a solution to make the text ellipsis without the help of JavaScript?

```css
div {
  max-width: 100px;
}

span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec accumsan risus et mauris rhoncus mattis.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but in IE contenteditable text ellipsis  is not possible.